# Adding metadata into pytest_configure file giving me internal error AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'metadata'

Tags: python, selenium, frameworks, pytest, pytest-html

I've imported pytest and installed pytest html too and I'm trying to add metadata into the pytest_configure file but when I run the test in the terminal I get back internal server error attribute not found

this is what is in the conftest file:

```
#hook for adding environment info to html report
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.metadata['Project Name'] = 'Hybrid Framework Practice' 
    config.metadata['Module Name'] = 'Customers'
    config.metadata['Tester'] = 'Amar'

#hook for delete/modify environment info to html report

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_metadata(metadata):
    metadata.pop("JAVA_HOME", None)
    metadata.pop("Plugins", None)
```

this is what i run in the terminal:

```
pytest -v -s -n=2 --html=Reports\report.html testCases\test_login.py --browser chrome
```

I'm following a guy on youtube and it seems to run for him using exact same code, yet for me it fails.
Running the line above without the pytest_configure code works fine and the tests pass
Does anyone know what is missing?
thanks

Comment: What is this metadata in `config` - should it be added by some plugin, or where it comes from? Add what is it used for?

Comment: it's for choosing the environment variables you want used in the pytest html report. I'm new to python so still learning, but it's working now , the metadata needed to be written as 'config._metadata', thank you @MrBeanBremen

Answer (score 2):

After installing pytest-html and pytest-metadata I was still getting the AttributeError. According to this [article](https://plainenglish.io/blog/create-your-customized-html-report-in-pytest-9c6b521b7e99), it seems that the problem was in the syntax. Based on your examples,the following version worked for me:

```
 config._metadata = {
            "Tester": "Amar",
            "Project Name": "Hybrid Framework Practice",
        }
```

The correct way to update the 'config._metadata' dictionary in pytest is by assigning a new one to it. The reason for this is that the config._metadata attribute in pytest is not a regular dictionary but a special metadata object. When you assign a new dictionary to it, you are replacing the existing metadata object with a new one that contains your custom metadata.

On the other hand, using config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Hybrid Framework Practice' would only work if the config._metadata object is already initialized as a dictionary. If it is not initialized or is of a different type, assigning a new key-value pair using square brackets would raise an error.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hey just replace metadata with _metadata.

eg:

```
config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Hybrid Framework Practice'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you extend your answer with some information why `_metadata` is necessary here instead of `metadata`? Maybe a link to the documentation or some detail so that the asker knows when they to use which in the furure.

Comment: with pytest7, you need to explicitly `pip install pytest-metadata`, it is no longer automatically installed, https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-metadata